# looking for a regex pattern key:value pairs

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex pattern for the outlook search, I am looking for grouping pattern to handle this

```
from:Jack subject:(sending invoice) title:ibm
```

I used this pattern but i do not get the words after the first word

```
(?<name>\\w+):[(](?<value>\\w*)[)]*
```

Comment: can you be clearer about what you are trying to achieve with your regex?

Answer (score 1):

`\w` doesn't handle spaces, change your regex to:

```
(?<name>\\w+):[(](?<value>[^)]*)[)]
```

`[^)]*` means 0 or more characters that is not right parens.

May be you'd prefer to use `[^)]+` that means ONE or more characters that is not right parens.

If the parenthesis are optional, use:

```
(?<name>\\w+):[(]?(?<value>[^)]+)[)]?
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How do i make the the parenthesis optional when there is only one word for the value:  from:Jack

Comment: @user1334070: Make them optional with the quantifier `?`, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The first bracket in 'value' is not optional in your regex

from:Jack subject:(sending invoice) title:ibm

As for whitespaces, I'd do it this way, as the brackets are not present in every key value pair anyway:

```
(?<name>\\w+):[(]*(?<value>(?:\\w|\\s)+)[)]*
```

However, it seems that the value is either one word or a sequence of words but within enclosing brackets - let's re-write the regex then, otherwise you'll get the whole thing after ':' as the first value:

```
(?<name>\\w+):(?:(?<value>\\w+)|(?:\\((?<value>(?:\\w|\\s)+)))
```